# Preg_replace variables in server variables

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to make a quote system, but I how to get preg_replace variables into server variables?

Don't understand?, here is the script!

```
$input = preg_replace("#\[quote id=(.*?)\]#si", "<blockquote><p>" . $class->functions('\\1') . "</p><p>..</p></blockquote>", $input);
```

the problem: The function does not know what `\\1` means after $mysqli->real_escape_string() and returns `\1`, if I remove the real_escape_string it still says it does not exist in the database.. but it's there!!

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use backreference like this. You need to use preg_replace_callback like:

```
function callback_function($m) {
  return "<blockquote><p>" . $class->functions($m[1]) . "</p><p>..</p></blockquote>";
}
preg_replace_callback("#\[quote id=(.*?)\]#si", "callback_function", $input);
```

Comment: Almost working, but the preg_replace is INSIDE a class INSIDE a function.. how to?

Comment: If your PHP version is >= 5.3.0, you can use anonymous functions like: `preg_replace_callback("#\[quote id=(.*?)\]#si", function($m) { return "<blockquote><p>" . $class->functions($m[1]) . "</p><p>..</p></blockquote>"; }, $input);`, so that you do not have to define a function.

Comment: Thats working fine now, but after the escape of $m[1] it says there is no result, but I know it's there..

Comment: sorry I could not understand your last comment. $m[1] empty?

Comment: No, it gives the good ID.. but when I use it in a MySQL Query it says there is no message with the ID.. But if I run the query in PhpMyAdmin, or another tool it gives the right result.

Comment: Matched id must have something different from the original ID, like a space in front or at the end. You can try trimming matched value. Or better var_dump matched array ($m) to see what is different.

Comment: Is returns: `array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "[quote=47]" [1]=> string(2) "47" }` no spaces.. but no result.

Comment: That must be another issue within the method which fetches data from db. You may try to print sql and try to execute printed query on phpmyadmin. I think my answer solved your regex part :) would appreciate upvote/accept